# Regression with constrained independent variables that are highly correlated

Tags: regression, cross-validation

I am not sure if what I am trying to construct is correct; hence, I need your help.

I am trying to fit a regression model, of any type, to data with one response, and multiple independent variables. The problem is that the independent variables are highly correlated (0.9-1.0), but more importantly for each realization of y, the sum of the corresponding x's is constrained to be a specific value that I have.

Is fitting a regression model even possible here? If not, can you think of a way to characterize the relationship between y and the x's?

Thank you.

Comment: It's a question for [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/). I believe, one of your predictors should be excluded as it is dependent on other (its value is always `your_constraint - sum_of_others`) Fitting the model with correlating regressors is a multicollinearity problem - see http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/86269/what-is-the-effect-of-having-correlated-predictors-in-a-multiple-regression-mode

Comment: Thanks. Yes, you are right about leaving one variable out, and yes multicollinearity can be dealt with using factor analysis. But even with independent factors, how will I find a model if any exists?